# DataContext not refreshed when changing object value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a `grid` and its `DataContext` is assigned from code behind:

```
CustomerDataGrid.DataContext = _customerobj;
```

When some functions are executing, the `_customerobj` object gets changed:

```
_customerobj = obj;
```

But `DataContext` doesn't update according to the new object details. If I use the following it does update:

```
_customerobj = obj;
CustomerDataGrid.DataContext = _customerobj;
```

Do I need to follow the same when each time **_customerobj** is updated or have I missed something?

Comment: Does the type of your _customerobj implement INotifyPropertyChanged? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: I think you want a binding and INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Nathan- No it does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Do I need to implement that?

Comment: Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` won't solve this. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're experiencing **is not** caused by not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

When you do `CustomerDataGrid.DataContext = _customerobj;`, you're setting the `DataContext` to a certain value. When afterwards you're setting `_customerobj = obj;`, you're just giving a `_customerobj` a new value, but `DataContext` still references the original object, so it won't change.

For example:

```
string a = "hello";
string b = a; // b points to "hello"
a = "world";  // a points to "world"
              // but b's pointer doesn't change

Console.WriteLine(b); // Outputs "hello"
```

This means that you'll have to set the DataContext as well.

Note: This isn't actually the way things work for strings, since .NET strings are immutable, but hopefully this gets the point across.

Answer (score 4):

@AdiLester 's answer above is correct and is the reason this happens.
That said, if you'd rather set the DataContext only once, and still have the object change in the grid you could *wrap* your property (in a ViewModel for instance), bind the grid to the property and then when the property will change the grid will also change.

For example:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private MyObj _customerObj;
   public MyObj CustomerObj
   {
       get { return _customerObj;}
       set
        {
            if (_customerObj != value)
            {
                _customerObj = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CustomerObj"));
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
 MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
 vm.CustomerObj = //Whatever;
 CustomerDataGrid.DataContext = vm;
```

And when you bind your grid use: `{Binding CustomerObj}`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Johan Larsson, you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to let the UI know that the data has changed.

[This tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/208833-using-the-inotifypropertychanged-functionality/) details how in an uncomplicated way.